# Persistent Network (Ethernet) Connection Issue on Ubuntu 20.04 and ifupdown

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

We are currently facing an issue on Ubuntu 20.04. Our eth0 interface is managed by the ifupdown service (you can see a screenshot of the /etc/network/interfaces file below). Initially, the connection is established and functions properly. However, after a certain period of time, the connection goes offline and when we write

```
sudo mii-tool eth0
```

it shows no link. It’s worth noting that we switched from NetworkManager to ifupdown to address this issue, but unfortunately, the problem persists.

Here is our /etc/network/interfaces file -

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.115/24
```

[interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcJG9.png)

Here is our /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf file -

```
[main]
plugins=keyfile,ifupdown

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

[NetworkManager.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tg5pp.png)

When we execute the “ip link” command, the output shows “NO-CARRIER, BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP.” This observation suggests that there might not be a physical link established between the host address and the physical gigabit Ethernet module. Please note that the ethernet cables are connected-

[ip link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUJAC.png)

In addition, this is what we find when we type ethtool eth0. It says Link detected: no -

[ethtool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYTA5.png)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please, edit your question and replace these images with text.

Comment: Thanks @sotirov for your reply. I have replaced the contents of the files with text.